# PDFLatex is counting numbers due to a parbox

Tags: boxes

I am having a problem with a `minipage` or `\parbox` and its parameters. Currently I try to do some business cards with the package called [`ticket`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ticket). Therefore I modified one example delivered with the package:

```
%%%%
%
% ticket.sty example file for visiting cards
%
%%%%
% use the corresponding paper size for your ticket definition
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{letter}

% load ticket.sty with the appropriate ticket definition
\usepackage[crossmark]{ticket}

\unitlength=1mm
\hoffset=-1.1cm
\voffset=-2cm
\ticketNumbers{2}{5}
\ticketSize{85}{55} % in unitlength
\ticketDistance{10}{0}    %in unitlength

% load misc stuff
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

% define something
\definecolor{uni}{rgb}{.3019,.7216,.7019}

% make your default ticket. \ticketdefault is somewhat like a background
% here it is empty, because we use different tickets for the front an
% the back of our card
\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{%
}

% now what do you like to put in your ticket
\newcommand{\vcardfront}[5]{\ticket{%
    \put(1,1){\parbox[c][55mm][c]{85mm}{#1}}%
 }}

\newcommand{\vcardback}[1]{\ticket{%
    \put( 7, 26){\small private:}
    \put( 5, 23){\color{uni}\line(1,0){56}}
    \put( 7,19){\small%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{50mm}%
          {#1}\hss%
        \end{minipage}}%
}}

% a counter, which makes life easier...
\newcounter{numcards}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

% ten cards for the front
\whiledo{\thenumcards<10}{%
  \stepcounter{numcards}%
  \vcardfront{Mr. XYZ}}

\setcounter{numcards}{0}

% and ten for the backside
\whiledo{\thenumcards<10}{%
  \stepcounter{numcards}%
  \vcardback{phone: ---/HH HH HHH\\fax: ---/HH HH HHH\\homestreet 7\\everywhere}}

\end{document}
```

Well and the problem is the `\vcardfront` command: as long as I use the `\parbox` inside the command in this way, pdfLaTeX won't come to an end and starts counting numbers in the log file:

```
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 55.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 55.

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17]
[18] [19] [20] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] [26] [27] [28] [29] [30] [31] [32]
[33] [34] [35] [36] [37] [38] [39] [40] [41] [42] [43] [44] [45] [46] [47]
[48] [49] [50] [51] [52] [53] [54] [55] [56] [57] [58] [59] [60] [61] [62]
[63] [64] [65] [66] [67] [68] [69] [70] [71] [72] [73] [74] [75] [76] [77]
[78] [79] [80] [81] [82] [83] [84] [85] [86] [87] [88] [89] [90] [91] [92]
[93] [94] [95] [96] [97] [98] [99] [100] [101] [102] [103] [104] [105] [106]
...
```

And it doesn't stop. But if I use a `\parbox` or `minipage` in the `\vcardback` way, it works. What have I done wrong? Why does it do that?

I'm using texlive 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what you want to produce, put perhaps this (I changed 5 to 1)

```
%%%%
%
% ticket.sty example file for visiting cards
%
%%%%
% use the corresponding paper size for your ticket definition
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{letter}

% load ticket.sty with the appropriate ticket definition
\usepackage[crossmark]{ticket}

\unitlength=1mm
\hoffset=-1.1cm
\voffset=-2cm
\ticketNumbers{2}{5}
\ticketSize{85}{55} % in unitlength
\ticketDistance{10}{0}    %in unitlength

% load misc stuff
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

% define something
\definecolor{uni}{rgb}{.3019,.7216,.7019}

% make your default ticket. \ticketdefault is somewhat like a background
% here it is empty, because we use different tickets for the front an
% the back of our card
\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{%
}

% now what do you like to put in your ticket
\newcommand{\vcardfront}[1]{\ticket{%
                         % 5????
    \put(1,1){\parbox[c][55mm][c]{85mm}{#1}}%
 }}

\newcommand{\vcardback}[1]{\ticket{%
    \put( 7, 26){\small private:}
    \put( 5, 23){\color{uni}\line(1,0){56}}
    \put( 7,19){\small%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{50mm}%
          {#1}\hss%
        \end{minipage}}%
}}

% a counter, which makes life easier...
\newcounter{numcards}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
% ten cards for the front
\whiledo{\value{numcards}<10 }{%
  \stepcounter{numcards}%
  \vcardfront{Mr. XYZ}%
}

\setcounter{numcards}{0}

% and ten for the backside
\whiledo{\value{numcards}<10 }{%
  \stepcounter{numcards}%
  \vcardback{phone: ---/HH HH HHH\\fax: ---/HH HH HHH\\homestreet 7\\everywhere}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I basically wanted to center the text from the argument on the whole card, but yes I didn't say that. Now it compiles again and I can try it.